# Are determinants supposed to be constant for square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have seen in a lot of Texts and Websites where the determinant for a square matrix is gotten by obtaining minors  along the first row which seems to be the norm. but recently I see it can be gotten by obtaining minors along the last column or across the diagonal(I see this a lot for obtaining the determinants for  4x4 matrices). so I decided to try this for the following 3x3 matrix(**A**)

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1^+&2^-&1^+\\
3^-&-4^+&-2^-\\
5^+&3^-&5^+\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**$(i)$** taking minors across the first row of $A$(the usual norm)

$$\det(A) = \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       1&-4&-2\\
      & 3&5\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       -2&3&-2\\
      & 5&5\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       1&3&-4\\
      & 5&3\\
       \end{array}  = -35
$$

*$(ii)$* taking minors across the last column of $A$
$$\det(A) = \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       1&3&-4\\
      & 5&3\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       -(-2)&1&2\\
      & 5&3\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       5&1&2\\
      & 3&-4\\
       \end{array}  = -35
$$

**$(iii)$** taking minors across the diagonal of $A$

$$\det(A) =  \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       1&-4&-2\\
      & 3&5\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       -(-4)&1&1\\
      & 5&5\\
       \end{array}  
       +
        \begin{array}{c|cc|}
       5&1&2\\
      & 3&-4\\
       \end{array}  = -64
$$

Why do I get a different value across the diagonal  if the determinant for any given matrix is constant irrespective of where the minors are obtained or are they all correct?

> **P.S:** case $(ii)$ result was corrected

Comment: If you redo the second case I think you will find that it does indeed give you -35

Comment: Minors along the diagonal?? Try with a $2\times 2$ matrix...

Comment: @ekkilop  the 2nd case as in `(ii)`. No it does not. $(9-(-20)) + -(-2)(3-10) + 5(-4-6) = -67$

Comment: You can compute determinants using the diagonals, but it is not the same method, check wikipedia for this as an easy source. Note that your calculation in case (ii) is simply wrong. If you take the minor along any row or column it should give the same number since the determinant does not depend on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your method. The only two methods I know for getting a determinant are 1) summing all the right diagonals and subtracting all the left diagonals and 2) summing/subtracting all of the possible contiguous 2X2 diagonals within any size matrix. I cannot find the latter method described anywhere I look and I do not like the similar method described on the web sites I've found.

Comment: Your forgot a minus before the 20. (9-(-20))....

Comment: sorry my mistake. ..corrected

Comment: @poetasis the method(recursive) I used in $(i)$ can be found in Engineering Maths by K.A.STROUD 6th Edition **pages 566,567**

Comment: It's still wrong... $(9-(-20))=29$. Next: $-(-2)(3-10)=2(3-10)=-14$. Next: $5(-4-6)=5(-10)=-50$. Adding them gives $29-14-50=15-50=-35$. Please be careful in calculating.

Comment: Jeez... thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to answer your question: you get different values for two different reasons. You are right that the determinant value of a matrix is independent of which minor we choose. Note however that choosing the diagonal is not a valid method for this. There are ways to compute the determinant using the diagonal, but not in the way you use here.

Secondly, your computation of (ii) is wrong, as pointed out in the comments. The reason the first row is usually chosen is for ease of methodology. If however you are working with a mtarix with zeros as entries it can be beneficial to choose that row or column to work with.